# React native - How to implement a switch between two values and show a different view based on the value selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, youtube, expo

**In my react native app, I need to show a Youtube style Inbox screen:**
A switch on top that has two values.
Based on the value selected in the switch,the expected behaviour is to show a different view and content for each value. The expected behaviour is also to be able swipe left and right to show these two differnet views. The switch should change its state based o the swipes of the views below: left or right.

for now, I am trying to use two distinct `touchableHighlight` as my switch but convinced this not the correct way to do it.
**Is there a specific react native component that fits this use case ?**

```
<View style = {styles.ButtonContainer}> 
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.Button}
    onPress={() => {
    this.setState({selector: 'ongoing'})
    }}>
    <Text style = {styles.ResetText}>On going</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight style={styles.Button}
    onPress={() => {
    this.setState({selector: 'archived'})            
    }}>
    <Text style = {styles.ApplyText}>Archived</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, what you are asking is a tabs feature.

You can try using **react-native-tab-view**

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view
2. https://reactnativeexample.com/a-windows-phone-style-tab-navigator-implemented-for-react-native/

Comment: Thank you @Divi , this is what i was looking for !